Interceptor in angular (version 12) is not getting called
Following is my interceptor code,
api.interceptor.ts

     import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, 
              HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
        
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

     @Injectable()
     export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

        intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
                                                    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

          // Update the last access time for every request.
          console.log('reached');
          return next.handle(req);
         }
      }

app.module.ts
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      Providers: [ {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
                             useClass: ApiInterceptor, multi: true}]`

Api.service.ts
        import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

         @Injectable({
           providedIn: 'root'
          })
       export class ApiService {
 

        constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) {
    
         }

       loadConfig(payload:IWorkflowPayload):Promise<IFrameConfigResponse> {
          return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.serverUrl+'/test',payload, 
                               { headers: this.headers }).toPromise();
         }

I do not where I had done wrong but when I load my app i see the interceptor is being called at any time. Can any one please suggest me the changes I have to do on my code. Thanks.

Which Angular version you used?

It's looks like work (see this stackblitz -return 403 but you can see in console the "reached". BTW is providers(the first in lowerCase) but I imagine it's a type error when you write the question.
